# 2 iPads, same iCloud account, but contacts lists are different!

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

As the title suggests, my 2 iPads have the same login, the same iCloud backup, but the contacts list on both is different.

**Is there a way I can merge the two so they're synced?**

My old iPad has most of the contacts I want, the new one has newer ones which weren't in the old one, so don't really want to lose either set!

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to revisit your question as I think we're missing some detail here. For example, you say that your two iPads share the same iCloud *backup* - is that what you meant to say or do you just mean they share the same iCloud account? Can you explain how you set up your new iPad? Also, is your iCloud Apple ID the only one you use, or do you have multiple Apple IDs? Finally, what versions of iOS are installed on your iPads?

Comment: Both have version 12.1.1. They have the same apple id to log in, and both have the same iCloud account. There is only 1 apple ID, not multiple.

Comment: @Giovanni Try hiding your iCloud Contacts. You may have added Contacts to the "On my iPad" list. Also, you can try disable and enable again the iCloud contact sync. This's will force a complete Sync.

Answer (score 1):

Are both iPads synchronized to the same email accounts?  FOr example, my iPhone only Gmail access but my iPad Pro has access to multiple Gmail and Hotmail accounts.  This could account for the variation.  The only way I know to fix mismatched contact lists is to either export one and merge it into the other one.  I'm not sure how easily this would be on an iPad, but if you can send them both to a Gmail account, Gmail has the ability to detect/merge duplicates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The contact lists are a combination of multiple storage types. They can contain iCloud contacts as well as other accounts and local entries.